# Visual Basic Script not working on startup

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I have a VB script with a corresponding .bat file that puts it in the "C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
folder. However, on startup the script does not fully run. The script is supposed to make taskbar shortcuts, but does not make them for the Office products I have listed.

Here is the script:

```
    Option Explicit

Const CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS = &H17
Const CSIDL_PROGRAMS = &H2
Const CSIDL_STARTMENU = &HB
Const CSIDL_CURRENT_USER_DESKTOP = &H10
Const CSIDL_PUBLIC_DESKTOP = &H19

Dim objShell, objFSO

Dim objCurrentUserStartFolder
Dim strCurrentUserStartFolderPath

Dim objCurrentUserDesktopFolder
Dim strCurrentUserDesktopFolderPath

Dim objAllUsersProgramsFolder
Dim strAllUsersProgramsPath

Dim objPublicDesktopFolder
Dim strPublicDesktopFolderPath

Dim objFolder
Dim objFolderItem
Dim colVerbs
Dim objVerb

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objCurrentUserStartFolder = objShell.NameSpace (CSIDL_STARTMENU)
strCurrentUserStartFolderPath = objCurrentUserStartFolder.Self.Path

Set objCurrentUserDesktopFolder = objShell.NameSpace (CSIDL_CURRENT_USER_DESKTOP)
strCurrentUserDesktopFolderPath = objCurrentUserDesktopFolder.Self.Path

Set objAllUsersProgramsFolder = objShell.NameSpace(CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS)
strAllUsersProgramsPath = objAllUsersProgramsFolder.Self.Path

Set objPublicDesktopFolder = objShell.NameSpace (CSIDL_PUBLIC_DESKTOP)
strCurrentUserDesktopFolderPath = objPublicDesktopFolder.Self.Path

' - Remove pinned items -

'Internet Explorer
If objFSO.FileExists(strCurrentUserStartFolderPath & "\Programs\Internet Explorer.lnk") Then
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(strCurrentUserStartFolderPath & "\Programs")
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("Internet Explorer.lnk")
    Set colVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs
    For Each objVerb in colVerbs
        If Replace(objVerb.name, "&", "") = "Unpin from Taskbar" Then objVerb.DoIt
    Next
End If

'Google Chrome
If objFSO.FileExists(strAllUsersProgramsPath & "\Google Chrome\Google Chrome.lnk") Then
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(strAllUsersProgramsPath & "\Google Chrome")
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("Google Chrome.lnk")
    Set colVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs
    For Each objVerb in colVerbs
        If Replace(objVerb.name, "&", "") = "Unpin from Taskbar" Then objVerb.DoIt
    Next
End If

'Windows Explorer
If objFSO.FileExists(strCurrentUserStartFolderPath & "\Programs\Accessories\Windows Explorer.lnk") Then
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(strCurrentUserStartFolderPath & "\Programs\Accessories")
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("Windows Explorer.lnk")
    Set colVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs
    For Each objVerb in colVerbs
        If Replace(objVerb.name, "&", "") = "Unpin from Taskbar" Then objVerb.DoIt
    Next
End If

'Windows Media Player
If objFSO.FileExists(strAllUsersProgramsPath & "\Windows Media Player.lnk") Then
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(strAllUsersProgramsPath)
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("Windows Media Player.lnk")
    Set colVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs
    For Each objVerb in colVerbs
        If Replace(objVerb.name, "&", "") = "Unpin from Taskbar" Then objVerb.DoIt
    Next
End If

' - Pin to Taskbar -

'Mozilla Firefox
If objFSO.FileExists("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Mozilla Firefox.lnk") Then
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\")
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("Mozilla Firefox.lnk")
    Set colVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs
    For Each objVerb in colVerbs
        If Replace(objVerb.name, "&", "") = "Pin to Taskbar" Then objVerb.DoIt
    Next
End If

'Windows Explorer
If objFSO.FileExists(strCurrentUserStartFolderPath & "\Programs\Accessories\Windows Explorer.lnk") Then
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(strCurrentUserStartFolderPath & "\Programs\Accessories")
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("Windows Explorer.lnk")
    Set colVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs
    For Each objVerb in colVerbs
        If Replace(objVerb.name, "&", "") = "Pin to Taskbar" Then objVerb.DoIt
    Next
End If

'Microsoft Office Word
If objFSO.FileExists("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office\Microsoft Office 2013\Word 2013.lnk") Then
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office\Microsoft Office 2013\")
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("Word 2013.lnk")
    Set colVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs
    For Each objVerb in colVerbs
            If Replace(objVerb.name, "&", "") = "Pin to Taskbar" Then objVerb.DoIt
    Next
End If

'Microsoft Office Excel
If objFSO.FileExists("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office\Microsoft Office 2013\Excel 2013.lnk") Then
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office\Microsoft Office 2013\")
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("Excel 2013.lnk")
    Set colVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs
    For Each objVerb in colVerbs
            If Replace(objVerb.name, "&", "") = "Pin to Taskbar" Then objVerb.DoIt
    Next
End If

'Microsoft Office Powerpoint
If objFSO.FileExists("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office\Microsoft Office 2013\PowerPoint 2013.lnk") Then
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office\Microsoft Office 2013\")
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("PowerPoint 2013.lnk")
    Set colVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs
    For Each objVerb in colVerbs
            If Replace(objVerb.name, "&", "") = "Pin to Taskbar" Then objVerb.DoIt
    Next
End If

' - Remove IE shortcuts from start menu -

'Internet Explorer
If objFSO.FileExists(strCurrentUserStartFolderPath & "\Programs\Internet Explorer.lnk") Then
    objFSO.DeleteFile(strCurrentUserStartFolderPath & "\Programs\Internet Explorer.lnk")
End If

'Internet Explorer 64-bit
If objFSO.FileExists(strCurrentUserStartFolderPath & "\Programs\Internet Explorer (64-bit).lnk") Then
    objFSO.DeleteFile(strCurrentUserStartFolderPath & "\Programs\Internet Explorer (64-bit).lnk")
End If


' - Remove Thunderbird from current user desktop -
If objFSO.FileExists(strCurrentUserDesktopFolderPath & "\Mozilla Thunderbird.lnk") Then
    objFSO.DeleteFile(strCurrentUserDesktopFolderPath & "\Mozilla Thunderbird.lnk")
End If

' - Remove Thunderbird from public desktop -
If objFSO.FileExists(strPublicDesktopFolderPath& "\Mozilla Thunderbird.lnk") Then
    objFSO.DeleteFile(strPublicDesktopFolderPath& "\Mozilla Thunderbird.lnk")
End If

' - Remove Google Chrome from current user desktop -
If objFSO.FileExists(strCurrentUserDesktopFolderPath & "\Google Chrome.lnk") Then
    objFSO.DeleteFile(strCurrentUserDesktopFolderPath & "\Google Chrome.lnk")
End If

' - Remove Google Chrome from Public desktop -
If objFSO.FileExists(strPublicDesktopFolderPath & "\Google Chrome.lnk") Then
    objFSO.DeleteFile(strPublicDesktopFolderPath & "\Google Chrome.lnk")
End If

'Delete the script
DeleteSelf

Sub DeleteSelf()
        Dim objFSO
        'Create a File System Object
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        'Delete the currently executing script
        objFSO.DeleteFile WScript.ScriptFullName
        Set objFSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

And here is the .bat file:

```
mkdir "C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
copy /y SetShortcuts.vbs "C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

Any ideas why this won't work?

ANSWER: I figured it out. I was getting the file path names wrong because the paths differ if there was a previous version of Office installed on the computer.

Comment: So, if the script is run once Windows is fully loaded, does it completely work? The issue can only be seen when the script is run on startup?

Comment: The best answer I can give to that is: "Sometimes". I just tried and it failed, but I tried it earlier and it worked. However, it always does everything right except for the office programs.

Comment: And are the failures consistent on a single machine? Or might it work one time and fail another?

Comment: I believe they are consistent. It looks like the script is running, so the only thing I can think of is that the paths for the office products are incorrect, but  I double-checked and they seem to be okay

Comment: My advice is to find a machine that consistently fails and one that consistently works. Then look for differences. Operating system, 32bit versus 64 bit, Office version, and if no luck, go on to patches to see if a patch is applied to one and not the other.

Comment: Maybe not work in the first time of new account login, when the user folder is preparing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER: I figured it out. I was getting the file path names wrong because the paths differ if there was a previous version of Office installed on the computer.

Answer (score 1):

> Default User profile is a template profile for all created users. Whenever you create a new user profile, the profile is built based on the Default User profile.

Copy the file to `"%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"` instead.